# How to use existing weights (in ndarray format) for tf.layers.dense in python?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to use existing matrix in ndarray format as initial weight to create a fully connected layer by using [`tensorflow.layers.dense`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dense). I am not sure how to do that. can anyone help? ideally I want to do following:

```py
weight = np.array([1,2,3],[1,2,3]) # as example
fully_connected = tf.layers.dense(input, hidden_unit, initializer = weight)
```

But I am not sure if possible I can directly do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify a custom kernel initializer. The docs for [`tf.layers.dense`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dense) do not do much to explain this, but show that you have the option at least. You can use:

```
init = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1, 2])
fc = tf.layers.dense(x, 3, kernel_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(init, dtype=tf.float32))
```

And to make sure it works:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    for v in vars:
        print('{}\n{}'.format(v.name, sess.run(v)))

# dense_7/kernel:0
# [[ 1.  2.  3.]
#  [ 4.  5.  6.]]
# dense_7/bias:0
# [ 0.  0.  0.]
```

The docs for [`tf.constant_initializer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/constant_initializer).

Note that you have to provide an input tensor to `tf.layers.dense` that specifies your input shape, thus `x` in the above, and you have to provide a second argument that tells it the dimensionality of your output; the `3` in the above. The shape of `x` and the dimensionality of your output will depend on your problem and what shape your weight matrix needs to take.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. Count on the points if it turns out this runs propely you saved my week